# Use pretrained model and create another sequential model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, rnn

I have a pre-trained model, as below

[image: Image1]

Code for the above model is as below,which is working as expected and I have saved this model separately in ".h5" keras format

```
data= pd.read_csv('TrainPWM.csv')
data.values[:,0]
actual_pwm = data.values[:,0]
actual_rpm = data.values[:,1]
actual_pwm = np.reshape(actual_pwm,(36954,1,1))/10000
actual_rpm = np.reshape(actual_rpm,(36954,1,1))/10000
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(actual_pwm,actual_rpm,test_size=0.3,random_state=50)
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=1,return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=20,return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=20,return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=1,return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mean_absolute_error',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1)
```

Now I want to create another sequential model, which must be trained with the above pretrained model(rnn2), below some explanation

[image: Image2]

I must create a sequential training model based on this where,When I give input x, first rnn1 must train itself based on the output y using rnn2

I have trouble visualizing the way to do this